# Color function: darken and lighten

Tags: java, graphics, colors

I'm currently writing a program that will render my minecraft world.
It's rendering lovely!
The issue is the maths involved in the next bit:
I want to give my function an average height and a current height.

If the height is lower than the average height, I'm going to overlay this section with a black, the transparency of this is going to be dependent on the amount but also clamped as to not make it pitch black.

Here's what I currently have:

```
public Color getHeightColor(float averageHeight, float height) {
    if (averageHeight > height) {
        return new Color(0, 0, 0, clamp(height / averageHeight, 0f, 0.8f));
    } else {
        return new Color(1, 1, 1, clamp(averageHeight / height, 0f, 0.8f));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't doing anything I want it to do, I just can't figure out a good method of doing this as I'm incredibly bad at maths.

Edit: After some thought, I'm going to do away with the lightening and instead, just darken it to give it a sense of depth.

Can any of you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure exactly what color you want here, however if you want higher than average to be brighter and lower than average to be darker then do something like :

```
// This assumes both args are positive and non-zero
public Color getHeightColor(float averageHeight, float height) {
    if (averageHeight > height) {
        return new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f - (height / averageHeight));
    } else {
        return new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f - (averageHeight / height));
    }
}
```